# How do I get the key at a specific index from a Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift

I have a `Dictionary` in Swift and I would like to get a key at a specific index.

```
var myDict : Dictionary<String,MyClass> = Dictionary<String,MyClass>()
```

I know that I can iterate over the keys and log them

```
for key in myDict.keys{

    NSLog("key = \(key)")

}
```

However, strangely enough, something like this is not possible

```
var key : String = myDict.keys[0]
```

Why ?

Comment: Just so you know, Swift dictionaries are not guaranteed to be in any specific order. So you can't expect for sure that the keys to be indexed in the order you put them in.

Comment: +1 @radex and also would like to add, if possible, a source to read more about your statement would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

That's because `keys` returns `LazyMapCollection<[Key : Value], Key>`, which can't be subscripted with an `Int`. One way to handle this is to advance the dictionary's `startIndex` by the integer that you wanted to subscript by, for example:

```
let intIndex = 1 // where intIndex < myDictionary.count
let index = myDictionary.index(myDictionary.startIndex, offsetBy: intIndex)
myDictionary.keys[index]
```

Another possible solution would be to initialize an array with `keys` as input, then you can use integer subscripts on the result:

```
let firstKey = Array(myDictionary.keys)[0] // or .first
```

Remember, dictionaries are inherently unordered, so don't expect the key at a given index to always be the same.

Comment: Probably faster would be `Array(myDict)[0].0` since it wouldn't copy the keys array, and shouldn't copy the internal structures of the dictionary, although it might.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are no promise about which key this will return, but good note about the "view" type that is returned. Deleted my answer since it didn't actually apply to the question.

Comment: To clarify what Rob is saying, while it may *seem* like the keys are always ordered the same every time, this is not the case and is simply an implementation detail. It's very possible that you could add the key "foo" and the internal representation will completely reorder the dictionary. A dictionary is an **unordered** collection of key-value pairs. Therefore, the answer above is making dangerous assumptions that do not hold true.

Comment: If you need the keys in a specific order, keep an array of them. Then you can use them like `myDict[keysArray[0]]`.

Comment: Doesn't work... `'NSDictionary' is not convertible to '_ArrayBuffer<T>'`

Comment: @Chris this is about the Swift Dictionary type, not NSDictionary. Are you getting this error in Xcode 6.3?

Comment: @0x7fffffff: ahh... got it. Was a lil bit late yesterday ;-) I'm running Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: There is no `advancedBy` method.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei There used to be when I originally wrote this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MickMacCallum, I found the correct solution meanwhile, and I also fixed your update.

Answer (score 70):

Swift 3 : `Array()` can be useful to do this .

**Get Key :**

```
let index = 5 // Int Value
Array(myDict)[index].key
```

**Get Value :**

```
Array(myDict)[index].value
```

Comment: This works for me for Swift 3. Don't understand why the created Array is re-arranged though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks this helped me

Comment: @josef What about it is counter intuitive? Dictionaries are key, value pairs, so the idea of an index doesn't fix. Arrays are accessed by index, so this turns a dictionary INTO an Array, and then accesses the array by it's index. A dictionary like `["a": 1, "b": 2]`, can be turned into an array of dictionaries like `[[key: "a", value: 1], [key: "b", value: 2]]`, this can then be accessed by index.

Comment: Thanks, the way is to convert it to array first. But it is really annoying when apply it in real project. Like this one `cell.artwork.image = Array(albumDict)[indexPath.item].value.first?.artwork?.image`, I use this shit long chain just to get a value from the values.

Answer (score 29):

Here is a small extension for accessing keys and values in dictionary by index:

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(i: Int) -> (key: Key, value: Value) {
        return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)]
    }
}
```

Comment: 'advance' API has been removed in Swift 2.0
use  -- self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)] --

Comment: @TomSawyer dictionaries aren't ordered.

Answer (score 11):

You can iterate over a dictionary and grab an index with for-in and enumerate (like others have said, there is no guarantee it will come out ordered like below)

```
let dict = ["c": 123, "d": 045, "a": 456]

for (index, entry) in enumerate(dict) {
    println(index)   // 0       1        2
    println(entry)   // (d, 45) (c, 123) (a, 456)
}
```

If you want to sort first..

```
var sortedKeysArray = sorted(dict) { $0.0 < $1.0 }
println(sortedKeysArray)   // [(a, 456), (c, 123), (d, 45)]

var sortedValuesArray = sorted(dict) { $0.1 < $1.1 }
println(sortedValuesArray) // [(d, 45), (c, 123), (a, 456)]
```

then iterate.

```
for (index, entry) in enumerate(sortedKeysArray) {
    println(index)    // 0   1   2
    println(entry.0)  // a   c   d
    println(entry.1)  // 456 123 45
}
```

If you want to create an ordered dictionary, you should look into Generics.

Comment: what if i wanted to search for what the index was for a equal to 456?

Comment: @Max, this is old Swift syntax. Now you can use:

`dict.enumerated().forEach { (index, element) in ... }`

Answer (score 10):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/CollectionTypes.html:

If you need to use a dictionary’s keys or values with an API that takes an Array instance, initialize a new array with the keys or values property:

```
let airportCodes = [String](airports.keys) // airportCodes is ["TYO", "LHR"]   
let airportNames = [String](airports.values) // airportNames is ["Tokyo", "London Heathrow"]
```

Answer (score 7):

SWIFT 3. Example for the first element

```
let wordByLanguage = ["English": 5, "Spanish": 4, "Polish": 3, "Arabic": 2]

if let firstLang = wordByLanguage.first?.key {
    print(firstLang)  // English
}
```

Comment: What if i wanted to get the index where key is Polish?

Answer (score 7):

In **Swift 3** try to use this code to get Key-Value Pair (tuple) at given index:

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(i:Int) -> (key:Key,value:Value) {
        get {
            return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### SWIFT 4

---

**Slightly off-topic:** But here is if you have an
**Array of Dictionaries** **i.e:** [ [String : String] ]

```
var array_has_dictionary = [ // Start of array

   // Dictionary 1

   [ 
     "name" : "xxxx",
     "age" : "xxxx",
     "last_name":"xxx"
   ],

   // Dictionary 2

   [ 
     "name" : "yyy",
     "age" : "yyy",
     "last_name":"yyy"
   ],

 ] // end of array


cell.textLabel?.text =  Array(array_has_dictionary[1])[1].key
// Output: age -> yyy
```

Comment: How can I get the index of the item that has age = xxxx in your example?

Comment: arrayIndex = 0,
ageDictIndex = 1,
Array(array_has_dictionary[arrayIndex].keys)[ageDictIndex] = xxxx

Comment: @FamicTech, Kris answered your question

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, using Swift 1.2

```
var person = ["name":"Sean", "gender":"male"]
person.keys.array[1] // "gender", get a dictionary key at specific index 
person.values.array[1] // "male", get a dictionary value at specific index
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like a LinkedHashMap in Java. Neither Swift nor Objective-C  have one if I'm not mistaken.

My initial thought was to wrap my dictionary in an Array. `[[String: UIImage]]` but then I realized that grabbing the key from the dictionary was wacky with `Array(dict)[index].key` so I went with Tuples. Now my array looks like `[(String, UIImage)]` so I can retrieve it by `tuple.0`. No more converting it to an Array. Just my 2 cents.