# How to get the index of a specific object in Dictionary in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, flatmap

I am searching a value of a key in `Dictionary Array` in this way.

```
if let result = self.lasrIDArray.flatMap({$0["\(self.selectedTitle)"]}).first  {
            print("-------RESULT------\(result)") //->title of the other
}
```

But wat I want to do is take the index of this `result` contains object.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find index of list item in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-swift)

Comment: For dictionaries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640990/how-do-i-get-the-key-at-a-specific-index-from-a-dictionary-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate array:

```
if let indexAndResultTuple = (self.lasrIDArray.enumerate().filter{$0.element["\(self.selectedTitle)"] != nil}).first {
    let index = indexAndResultTuple.0
    let result = indexAndResultTuple.1["\(self.selectedTitle)"]!

    print("-------RESULT------\(result) --atIndex--\(index)") //->title of the other
}
```

Comment: @dfri if I understood question, there is array of dictionaries, and we need index of first dictionary that contains value for key "\(self.selectedTitle)"

Comment: On a closer look on the somewhat sparsely described question, I believe you're right, my bad!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me what is the index at $0.index

Comment: I am getting a syntax error near the comma at $0.index, it asking me to add ;

Comment: @Irrd looks like syntax bug. Check my answer edited changes

Comment: I got the result . when I print the indexAndResultTuple it shows as 0,nil but that key is not the 0th index. but im always getting this result. Why is that?

Comment: @Irrd did you try last version of my code? indexAndResultTuple can not have nil as second value

Answer (score 0):

try

for item in self.lasrIDArray
{

if self.lasrIDArray.containsObject(item.valueForKey("yourKey")!){

//your logic here

}
}

Comment: its an array of dictionary objects. same key can be repeat